# Google Drive API V3 - changes.watch "params" property

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

as explained in the the docs here https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/changes/watch

There is a property named "params" that you can use when starting to watch for changes on a drive account. The docs describe it as "Additional parameters controlling delivery channel behavior."

Does anyone know what kind of properties we can use in this "params" object? I can't find any kind of documentation about it.

Thanks

Comment: I've checked it but didn't find any document regarding what properties you can use in `params` object. Seeing that Google Cloud also has [`Objects: watchAll`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/watchAll) and has `params` object too, I could only guess that it is any additional property for  controlling delivery channel behavior. It is still vague to what are those additional parameters, I suggest that you create a [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191650&template=823909) regarding the documentation for `changes:watch`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I created a bug report.